# C++ private static constexpr member variables

Tags: c++, private, constexpr, static-members

So I'm wondering, given the simple class:

```
//Foo.h
class Foo {
private:
    static constexpr int bar = 0;

public:
    int do_something();
};

//Foo.cpp
int Foo::do_something() {
    return 5 + bar;
}
```

Would it be reasonable to completely remove `bar` from the header as its a private static constexpr value thats never used in the header file?

If it were to just be floating at the top of the cpp file instead, it would effectively provide the same functionality, with the added bonus of cleaning up the header file a little.

Are there any reasons not to do this?

Edit: For clarification, these variables may be used in one or more functions, one or more times, and NEVER in the header file.

In my use case, these variables are constant limits/vecs, an example:

```
static constexpr float rotLimitVertical = to_rad(90.0f);
static constexpr float rotLimitHorizontal = to_rad(360.0f);

static const glm::vec3 right    = {1, 0, 0};
static const glm::vec3 up       = {0, 1, 0};
static const glm::vec3 forward  = {0, 0, 1};
```

which I would like to keep at the top of the file to make them easy to tweak if need be (especially in the case the variable is only used in one function, sure it may make sense to change it to a local variable, but that makes it more annoying to find to adjust).

Comment: You should note that there's a difference about simply `const` and `constexpr`.

Comment: "_If it were to just be floating at the top of the cpp file instead, it would effectively provide the same functionality_" It wouldn't be scoped inside of `Foo` though, allowing any functions (belonging to `Foo`, or not) in such .cpp, to "see" such variable.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I know that there is a difference, but in this situation, would it make much if any difference?

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius are you sure? My compiler happily allows this... (msvc)

Comment: @HexCrown Please re-read my comment. It's unclear to me, what you are replying to, since your reply doesn't seem to match my comment. I didn't state if something were, or were not allowed. I stated, how the functionality would differ, between those cases.

Comment: How is this bar used? If the only usage of it is in a single function, I do not see a reason for it's existence.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux as the original post says "...thats never used in the header file...", so the member variable std::array<int, bar> doesn't really fit my question

Comment: @SergeyA in the above example, its only used once, but in my situation, sometimes there used in multiple locations, sometimes multiple times in one function.

Comment: @HexCrown the scope of the variable will be defined by the usage pattern.

Answer (score 4):

> Are there any reasons not to do this?

I think it is better to move it to the .cpp file.  You can make it:

1. A file scoped `static` variable, or
2. A variable in the anonymous namespace in the .cpp file, or
3. A variable in the namespace that is specific to the .cpp file.

---

#### Option 1

```
static constexpr int bar = 0;
```

#### Option 2

```
namespace
{
   constexpr int bar = 0;
}
```

#### Option 3

```
namespace MyFile_Namespace
{
   constexpr int bar = 0;
}
```

Comment: By option 1 you mean, place it at the top of the cpp file like I proposed correct? Example: Foo.cpp `#include "Foo.h" static constexpr int bar = 0; //... rest of function definitions`

Comment: @HexCrown, yes.